# How many experiments to run (sample-size) if I know I am going to feed them to a non-parametric regression?

Tags: regression, sample-size, statistical-power, nonparametric-regression

I have 2 input variables, $X_1$ and $X_2$ that affect output variable $Y$. I can run experiments where I modify the inputs and measure what happens to the output.

Now, if $X_1$ and $X_2$ were binary, I could just run four sets of experiments, collect $Y$ and use t-test to figure out if any combination affects output differently. Most importantly i can use power tables to check what should the sample size for each experiment be in order to achieve a desired power level.

However, if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are continuous between 0 and 1 I am not sure how to compute sample size and power. I am willing to assume some form of continuous function connecting $Y$ to $f(X_1,X_2)$ although not necessarily a linear one, but I am unclear about what my power is when I check, for example, if the difference between $f(X_1,X_2)$ and $f(X_1,X_2+h)$ is significant or not.
And given this, can I figure out what the sample size ought to be?

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to accomplish?  It sounds something like [response surface modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Response_surface_methodology), but then power is not a principal concern.

Comment: Well at the end of the day I want to know how sure I am whether f(x) and f(x') are different (for arbitrary x, x'). I want to run just enough simulations (probably sampling at random uniformly around x, x') to achieve a given level of confidence

Comment: Your question is ill-defined: what would "arbitrary x, x'" possibly mean?  If randomly chosen, sometimes they will be so close that no amount of sampling could possibly distinguish the responses.

Comment: Exactly! is there a function/table connecting distance between X and sample size needed to be sure the response are different when the regression says they are?

Comment: When you do the experiment with just two values of $X,$ yes there is such a function.  In general there is not: it depends on all the values of $X$ you use, on the nature of $f,$ and even on the experimental design (*e.g.*, whether it is adaptive).  You can't figure out sample size until you have specified the experiment in full detail.